# Create a slideshow from external links

Tags: 7, javascript, views

Is it possible to create a slideshow using( slideshow module or views slideshow module or anything else) external image url's  instead of downloading the images, then uploading in the image field?

Also I'm looking for a functionality where there are some image fields( containing uploaded images) and some external image links but all need to be shown in single slideshow.

I've googled this but could not find anything useful ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Embedded Image Field](https://drupal.org/project/emfield) module supports third party image content and also you can integrate with views.

Also look into below module

[Remote stream wrapper](https://drupal.org/project/remote_stream_wrapper) Provides the ability to use external files with file fields without saving the files to your local files directory. Also provides a 'Remote URL' browser plugin for Media. see [DEMO](http://www.flickr.com/photos/davereid20/sets/72157627173464529/show/)

Comment: What is the use of Remote stream wrapper? I can't use it to show slideshow.

Comment: @AgA I'm not using this before, It provides a 'Remote URL' browser plugin for Media- see this below image link it shows the external image attached - http://www.flickr.com/photos/davereid20/5983452962/in/set-72157627173464529

Comment: @AgA see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099363/embed-external-image-links-in-node-fields-without-downloading-them-to-own-site